# json writer for nested classes

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.2, play-json, playframework-json

I'm using Play! Scala 2.2 and I have a problem to render a `class` in `Json` :

I have two classes with one depending of the other, as following :

```
case class Artist(id: String, cover: String, website: List[String], link: String, Tracks: List[Track] = List())

case class Track(stream_url: String, title: String, artwork_url: Option[String] )
```

And their implicit Writers :

```
implicit val artistWrites: Writes[Artist] = Json.writes[Artist]

implicit val trackWrites: Writes[Track] = Json.writes[Track]
```

The writers work well as following :

```
println(Json.toJson(Track("aaa", "aaa", Some("aaa"))))
println(Json.toJson(Artist("aaa", "aaa", List("aaa"), "aaa", List())))
```

i.e if the `Artist` have an **empty** `list of tracks`.
But if I want to do this :

```
println(Json.toJson(Artist("aaa", "aaa", List("aaa"), "aaa", List(SoundCloudTrack("ljkjk", "ljklkj", Some("lkjljk"))))))
```

I get an `execution exception` : `[NullPointerException: null]`

Can you please explain me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the initialization order. `Json.writes[Artist]` requires an implicit `Writes[Track]` in order to generate itself. The compiler is able to find the implicit `Writes[Track]`, because you're declaring it in the same object, *however* `trackWrites` is initialized *after* `artistWrites`, which means that when `Json.writes[Artist]` is called, `trackWrites` is `null`. This doesn't interrupt the creation of `artistWrites`, however, so it goes unnoticed until it's actually used.

You can fix this by simply switching the initialization order, so that `trackWrites` is first.

Comment: It's easy to fall into this trap because the compiler doesn't emit any warnings about this. Probably 99% of the NPEs I get in Scala occur from initialization order problems.

Answer (score 0):

With Play 2.8, it is really simple to do, following works for me:

Let's suppose I had three classes:

```
case class InnerBean(fieldName: String, status: String, ruleCode: Int, subRuleCode: List[Int])

case class IntermediateBean(itemId: Long, innerBeanData: Option[List[InnerBean]])

case class OuterBean(uniqueTrackingId: String, intermediateBeanData: List[IntermediateBean])

implicit val innerBeanWrites: Writes[InnerBean] = Json.writes[InnerBean]
implicit val intermediateBeanWrites: Writes[IntermediateBean] = Json.writes[IntermediateBean]
implicit val outerBeanWrites: Writes[OuterBean] = Json.writes[OuterBean]
```